# Div scrolling to top when wrapped in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scrollable div. Scrolling down and then wrapping the div into another div causes the scroll position to be reset to top. Any ideas on how to preserve the scroll position?

HTML:

```
<div class="box"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
<button onclick="wrapme()">wrap me!</button>
```

JS:

```
function wrapme(){
    $(document.body).wrapInner($("<div>", { class: "wrapper" }));
}
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyd3r70k/5/

Comment: Where  do you include the JS on your website?

Comment: Your fiddle does not represent your code in your post, it is also missing JQuery dependency, and throwing a JS error when clicking on your button... Fix this and maybe we can help you proper.

Comment: Sorry, changes were not saved. I’ve updated the fiddle. JS is included in head.

Answer (score 0):

You have to monitor and save your text "scrollTop".
Try this: http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/rrzAVk?editors=1111

```
function wrapme(){
  var top = $('.box').scrollTop();
    $(document.body).wrapInner($("<div>", { class: "wrapper" }));
  $('.box').scrollTop(top);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @g1un, I knew that but I wondered if there is another way of doing it without examining the element. I’m curious about this happening. If the only way of adding a parent to an element is cloning it, why the reference is then preserved?

Comment: @Ricardo I didn't understand.What reference do you speak of?

Comment: If you save a reference to the element (box in the example) and then wrap it inside a div, the reference doesn’t change. Or is the same jQuery element but a new DOM element?